# How do I find all references to an address with a memory segment?

Tags: radare2

If I want to find all references to `fs:[0x28]` how would I go about doing it with radare2? For example,

```
0x000006b5      64488b042528.  mov rax, qword fs:[0x28]    ; [0x28:8]=0x1978 ; '(' ; "x\x19"
```

I want to find all lines that reference `fs:[0x28]`, like the one above. This address is used as a [stack canary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10325915/124486), and I'm especially interested to see what is reading from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you can find the things writing to it with `axt` (*find data/code references to this address*) using just the address `0x28`. **I'm still unsure how to qualify the memory segment,**

```
[0x000006aa]> axt 0x28
sym.foo 0x6b5 [DATA] mov rax, qword fs:[0x28]
```

But this doesn't work,

```
[0x000006aa]> axt fs:[0x28]
entry0; [14] -r-x section size 514 named .text 0x5a0 [CODE] xor ebp, ebp
sym.__libc_csu_init 0x779 [CALL] call qword [r12 + rbx*8]
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking how this function is implemented, it looks like there's no option for this (but go ask on [r2's on Telegram](https://telegram.me/joinchat/ACR-FkEK2owJSzMUYjt_NQ)). It just takes a string that's being converted to a number and that's all. If you want to see all the places where `fs:[0x28]` being used why not search for this part of the opcode?

```
[0x004049a0]> /c fs:[0x28]
0x00402a19   # 9: mov rax, qword fs:[0x28]
0x00403f81   # 9: xor rcx, qword fs:[0x28]
0x00404dc1   # 9: mov rax, qword fs:[0x28]
0x00404de6   # 9: xor rdx, qword fs:[0x28]
0x00405431   # 9: mov rax, qword fs:[0x28]
0x004054ea   # 9: xor rbx, qword fs:[0x28]
...
```